Do transfer function changed in vertically placed spring damper system when an additional mass is added
Title: Calculating the Transfer Function and Displacement for a Spring-Damper System with Additional Mass

I am working on a problem involving a spring-damper system, and I need help with calculating the transfer function and the displacement when an additional mass is added. The system is described as follows:
System Description:

The system consists of a mass-spring-damper arrangement.
The mass of the system $ m $ is $40 kg$.
The spring constant $ k $ is $2 \times 10^4 Nm^{-1}$.
The damping constant $ b $ is $3 \times 10^4 Nm^{-1}$.
The transfer function is given by $ \frac{Y(s)}{F(s)} = \frac{1}{ms^2 + bs + k} $.

Problem Statement:
I need to calculate the displacement $ y(t) $ of the seat when a 40 kg driver sits on it. The key question is whether the effective mass in the transfer function should change due to the driver's weight.
If not changed why?
When the driver sits on the seat, their mass adds to the system's mass. Therefore, the effective mass becomes:
$ m_{\text{total}} = 40 \, \text{kg} (\text{shock absorber}) + 40 \, \text{kg} (\text{driver}) = 80 \, \text{kg} $
Calculation without considering mass of the driver:
Under static conditions (no dynamic forces, $ s = 0 $):
$ F = k y $
where:
$ F = 40 \, \text{kg} \times 9.81 \, \text{m/s}^2 = 392.4 \, \text{N} $
Therefore:
$ y = \frac{F}{k} = \frac{392.4 \, \text{N}}{20000 \, \text{N/m}} = 0.01962 \, \text{m} = 1.962 \, \text{cm} $
Question:

Is the approach correct for calculating the static displacement when the driver sits on the seat?
Why shouldn't we consider the combined mass as both massess can be assume as combined as both move with same velocity and acceleration(As I assume)?

Any help or clarification would be greatly appreciated!

Basically yes, when the driver sits on it the effective mass is 80 kg. I suspect they want you to use the weight of the driver to add an impulse to the system and set off the decaying bouncing motion, that is assumes the driver is hovering just above the seat and then sits in it.  therefore, without damping you'd expect the seat to start at -1.962 cm, and then bounce between -3.924 cm and 0
